# How to search with parameter in MVC5 without ef

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Please, I will be happy if I someone could help me on how to create a search page in MVC 5 without using entity framework. If a user enters a product name and post, the result is displayed in a `GridView` or in an `InputBox`/`Label` for single rows. I am using C# and SQLServer at the back end. I am just a beginner in MVC and C#.

I created a controller as shown below;

```
{
  connect pcon = new connect();
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pcon.CS))
  {
    try
    {
      //do something
      pcon.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbproduct WHERE itemName=@name)";
      pcon.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
      pcon.cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = p.itemName;
      pcon.cmd.Connection = conn;
      conn.Open();
      datagridview = pcon.cmd.ExecuteReader();
      TempData["Success"] = "Record Added Sucessfully.";
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // throw ex;
      // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product");
      return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Product", "AddProduct"));
    }    // end of try-catch
  }      // end of using
}        // end of spurious open bracket
```

With this, I don't know how I would pass it to a view to get a meaningful result.
Thank you

Comment: in mvc there is no gridview.

Comment: // end of spurious open bracket  - lol

Answer (score 0):

You could get the results from the `ExecuteReader` object and pass this down to your View.  I would also suggest some changes to the application's architecture.

Firstly I would have a ViewModel class which captures the entities you wish to pass down to the View. Something like:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    private ProductService _productService = new ProductService();

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(string name)
    {
       return _productService.GetProducts(name);
    }
}
```

I would suggest putting the ADO.NET code (SqlConnection, SqlCommand) into a different layer, i.e. a Data Access Layer or a ProductService.

```
public class ProductService
{
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetProducts(string name) 
    {
       List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pcon.CS))
       {
          // Your code here
          // Build up the products list from the SQL data reader
       }
       return products;
    }
}
```

This will keep your Controller light and free from business logic.

Within your Controller you would then have:

```
public ActionResult GetProduct(string product)
{
    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();
    var products = model.GetProducts(product);

    return View(products);
}
```

Then within your View (.cshtml) file you would iterate over the IEnumerable collection (You don't have a server side control like grid view), therefore you build your own.

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@foreach(var product in Model)
{
   @product.name
}
```

As an additional note you may want to consider using an ORM such as Entity Framework or nHibernate which can do all the uplifting for you.

Comment: Thanks so much Darren. I followed your precedure but i got confuse a bit. This is my product viewmodel:namespace POS.Models
{
  public  class ProductViewModel
    {
        private ProductService _productService = new ProductService();

        public IEnumerable<productModel> GetProducts(string name)
        {
            return _productService.GetProducts(name);
        } This is my product service: public IEnumerable<productModel> GetProducts(string name)
        { List<productModel> products = new List<productModel>();  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pcon.CS))

Comment: product service model cont..{
                pcon.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbproduct WHERE itemName=@name)";
                pcon.cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
pcon.cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value =name;
  pcon.cmd.Connection = conn;
    using (SqlDataReader reader = pcon.cmd.ExecuteReader())
  { while (reader.Read()) { products.Add(new productModel() { Description = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("itemDesc")),  quantity = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("quantity")),  }
               reader.Close();   return products;

Comment: this is my controller:  public ActionResult GetProduct(string product)
        {
            ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel();
            var products = model.GetProducts(product);

            return View(products);
        }

Comment: this is my view:(at)model IEnumerable<POS.Models.productModel>
(at){
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


(at)foreach (var product in Model)
{
    (at)product.itemName
}

Comment: pls if it is difficult to read this, kindly direct me how to send a comment with my code. i am using (at) to represent the at sign in the view. My problem is; i cant see how a input parameter (productName) is passed to the controller to fetch the search result to be displayed on the view. i was thinking http_post will be used to send the search key to the controller and the controller will fetch the search result from the model back to a view to display to the user. But am not able to visualise that. Kindly pardon me, i believe because am a new user is causing this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Actually your controller method needs to take some search parameter to search and return the results.

You can also create a viewmodel based on what properties/fields you want to display on the view then map the result to viewmodel and return it.

```
public ActionResult DoSearch(string searchString) 
{           
    var movies = <get the movie list>; 

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
    { 
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)); 
    }

    return View(movies); 
}
```

In view you can create a table by looping the model for displaying the results.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie> 
@  
if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
  <tr>
  <td colspan = "3" >Records not found</td>  
  </tr >  
}
else 
{      
    foreach(var item in Model) 
    { 
    <tr>
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem = > item.MovieName)</td>            
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</td>          
    </tr >  
    }  
}
```

For displaying for more attractive and user friendly table you can use `IPagedList` also.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search tutorial.